# design:28.0.0-rc01 Build Issue

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I have Android Studio to 3.1.4 and my Gradle to 4.4 and my SDK to 28 (Repository is installed too). so I get this error on my Design library all the time.

Inside my Gradle I have

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
```

And my log is:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01.
```

Comment: **28.0.0-rc01** Might have android studio preview issue BTW. Use stable versions like `27.1.1`. Anyways, did you use VPN for downloading ?

Comment: does 27.1.1 contain all material 2 features?
yes I did use VPN btw thanks for the suggestion

Comment: if you want material stuff use: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02'`, more: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Comment: @pskink Good point. However, she'll need to change the whole project to use **beta01** or **Release candidate** version of Material stuff which these dependencies can probably have some issues or problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `Build.gradle` where repositories are there -> `buildscript -> allprojects`:

```
repositories {
    google()
    maven { 
    url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' 
     }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
 }
}
```

Make sure *offline work* is not checked in :

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle
```

Uncheck the Offline work and then it should work fine.

Comment: The VPN you are using is not tunneling the android studio. Go to `File -> Settings -> Appearance & behavior -> Http proxy` and select `auto-detect proxy settings` and then it should work fine. If it didn't help, use OpenVPNs